# while altering the columns data type got error 'ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "" '?

Tags: postgresql

In my `vault_log` table there is a column `resp_id`, the data type is `varchar(40)` and I want to alter the data type from `varchar(40)` to `uuid` but I get this error when trying to do so:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type UUID:

This is the command I have used:

```
alter table vault_log 
    alter column resp_id type uuid using resp_id::uuid;
```

Table schema:

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ac | character varying(20) |  | not null |  |
| scheme_code | character varying(20) |  | not null |  |
| req_ts | timestamp without time zone |  | not null |  |
| res_ts | timestamp without time zone |  | not null |  |
| resp | character varying(20) |  | not null |  |
| err | character varying(20) |  |  |  |
| resp_id | character varying(40) |  | not null |  |
| txn | uuid |  | not null |  |
| client_ip | character varying(20) |  |  |  |
| opr | character varying(20) |  | not null |  |
| vault_id | integer |  | not null | nextval('vault_log_vault_id_seq'::regclass) |
| mac_id | character varying |  |  |  |

Comment: An empty string is not a valid UUID. Use NULL when there is no valid UUID, but you have to drop the current NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.
[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d28193a6cb90b30bd63b4ef05f60a393)
If not working means resp_id column stored some value(s) in it.
Obvious, everything can
be cast to text. further info, see [pg_cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html)

```
( SELECT DISTINCT
        typname
    FROM
        pg_cast c
        JOIN pg_type t ON c.casttarget = t.oid
    WHERE
        typname ILIKE '%uuid%')
UNION ALL ( SELECT DISTINCT
        typname
    FROM
        pg_cast c
        JOIN pg_type t ON c.castsource = t.oid
    WHERE
        typname ILIKE '%uuid%');
```

return zero rows.
zero rows means: There is no explicit cast to and from data type uuid.
So you should just add  an new uuid column.